# Is there a way to make a keydown listener work even when focused on an external iframe?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple browser game with keyboard navigation.

The problem is that I have iframes on the site and when the user clicks on one of the iframes the body event that detects keydowns simply doesn't work unless the user clicks outside the iframe again.

Is there a way to detect keydowns regardless if the user clicks on an external iframe?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot detect keypress on an **external** `iframe`.
In general, no scripts events can be run in an **external** `iframe` and that's by design.

Just think of all the possibilities a malicious user would one have with such a, I would say, security hole.

Answer (score 0):

If its the same domain you could potentially register the events on the iframe and the window.

If it's across different domains that you don't have access to in both places then, No.

If you have access to both domains then you could use some hash tag communication, or one of the other routes for cross domain communication.  Basically you would register the events in the iframe and window and simply invoke the windows event when the event occurs.

#### Another solution

Although potentially evil you could do some variant of the following.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.body.focus() 
}, 100 );
```

Also I'm not sure how cross browser it is.